# Unexpected type error with arrays

Tags: java

I have a lab that I have to do for my computer class and i have an error that I can't seem to figure out. I get the error on the first `if` statement, `if(something.indexOf(x) = "a")`. I want to change the other `if` statements to be of that form.

The error I get is:

> unexpected type
>     required:variable: found; value

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] input = new String[1000];
String[] output = new String[1000];
int x = 0;// All purpose counter
int y = 0;//Second purpose counter
boolean ends = false;
boolean starts = false;
/**
 * This method is supposed to take the dna array and create an rna array from it to return
 * to the main method wherever this method is called.
 * 
 * @param  String[] input     The array that contains the dna sequence
 * @return String[] output    The array that contains the mRNA we just created in this method
 */
public void makeRNA()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a simple DNA Sequence, make sure the amount of variables are a multiple of 3.");
    String something = in.nextLine();
    while(x < 1000)
    {
        if(something.indexOf(x) = "a")
        {
            output[x] = "u";
        }
        else if(input[x] == "c")
        {
            output[x] = "g";
        }
        else if(input[x] == "g")
        {
            output[x] = "c";
        }
        else if(input[x] == "t")
        {
            output[x] = "a";
        }            
        x++;
    }
    for(x = 0 ; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(output[x]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be here: `if(something.indexOf(x) = "a")`

- To get the character at index `x` you need to use [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29).
- Instead of the assignment operator, you need to use `==` (comparison operator).
- Compare it with a `char` and not a `String`, because [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) returns a char. So change `"a"` to `'a'`.

> So your statement should finally look like:
>   `if(something.charAt(x) == 'a')`

Answer (score 1):

`if(something.indexOf(x) = "a")` ,`=` is assignment operator. you need `==` operator in your if statement unless the assignment results in a boolean.

also, `indexOf()` returns an `int` ,so you can't use `==` with `"a"`, use `equals()` for string comparison.

java if statement doesn't work like c or c++.

Comment: then i get the error incompatible types: int and java.lang.String

Comment: that's because `indexOf()` returns an int and "a" is a string

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to use `.charAt()` ??

Answer (score 0):

Ramanlfc is correct in saying use == instead of = because just a single equals sign is an assignment operator.

However, I'm not sure your IF statements are doing what you want them to do. The indexOf() method returns an integer and you're trying to compare it to a string, an object, using == (equals). If you want to compare two strings use the .Equals() method. You cannot use == on an object, which is what a string is. However, you can use == on chars because they are primitive types. To specify a char use single quotes not double quotes (double quotes specifies a string which is currently how you have your if statement set up). I'm assuming java will use the hex value of the char to compare it to a number. Once again, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but just some helpful advice!

I'm assuming you want something like the following:
if(stringMsg.charAt(INDEXVALUE) == 'a')

This gets the character at the specified value in the string and checks to see if it is the same (equal to) the char a. Remember characters in a string are number 0 to (length - 1).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code:

```
if(something.indexOf(x) = "a") // it should be "==" instead of "="
```

The correct code is:

```
if(something.indexOf(x) == "a")
```

Please note that `if(something.indexOf(x) = "a") will always return true in java.`

Comment: Your answer won't compile. `indexOf()` will return an `int` and you are comparing it with a `String`.